# How to programically trigger notify on MutableLiveData change

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata

I have a LiveData property for login form state like this

```
private val _authFormState = MutableLiveData<AuthFormState>(AuthFormState())
val authFormState: LiveData<AuthFormState>
    get() =_authFormState
```

The AuthFormState data class has child data objects for each field

```
data class AuthFormState (
    var email: FieldState = FieldState(),
    var password: FieldState = FieldState()
)
```

and the FieldState class looks like so

```
data class FieldState(
    var error: Int? = null,
    var isValid: Boolean = false
)
```

When user types in some value into a field the respective FieldState object gets updated and assigned to the parent AuthFormState object

```
fun validateEmail(text: String) {
    _authFormState.value!!.email = //validation result
}
```

The problem is that the authFormState observer is not notified in this case.

Is it possible to trigger the notification programically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can do:

```
fun validateEmail(text: String) {
    val newO = _authFormState.value!!
    newO.email = //validation result
    _authFormState.setValue(newO)
}
```

Comment: I have this in place already :) but was looking for some simpler solution.

Comment: @yaugenka If You have it you should state it clearly in the question. This is a solution for the problem You asked in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the value to itself, like this: `_authFormState.value = _authFormState.value` to trigger the refresh. You could write an extension method to make this cleaner:

```
fun <T> MutableLiveData<T>.notifyValueModified() {
    value = value
}
```

For such a simple data class, I would recommend immutability to avoid issues like this altogether (replaces all those `var`s with `val`s). Replace `validateEmail()` with something like this:

```
fun validateEmail(email: String) = //some modified version of email
```

When validating fields, you can construct a new data object and set it to the live data.

```
fun validateFields() = _authFormState.value?.let {
        _authFormState.value = AuthFormState(
            validateEmail(it.email),
            validatePassword(it.password)
       )
    }
```

Comment: The immutable variant would require repeating each field in each field validation `fun`

Comment: See edit for how I'd do it if validating multiple fields. Regardless, immutable classes result in more robust code at a cost of some conciseness. IMO, a data class should be immutable unless you're trying to optimize something where many instances of it are used.